# Devexpress Gridcontrol Multiselect without using indicator column

Tags: devexpress, multi-select, gridcontrol

Is there any way to allow the user to do a multiple row selection just by clicking and dragging along cells within the actual grid?  I.e. Without using the indicator column?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by cell using just properties by setting the following properties located in Gridview.Options

```
 Multiselect = True
 MultiSelectMode = CellSelect
 UseIndicatorForSelection = False
```

If you need to do it by entire rows, you are stuck writing that functionality yourself using `GridView.CalcHitInfo` and various events.

Answer (score 0):

> To achieve this behavior, you need to handle the MouseDown and
>   MouseMove events and select rows programmatically. You also need to
>   `enable` the `multi-selection` feature and switch the `multi-selection
>   mode` to "`CellSelect`" to be able to select individual cells.

download the attached sample from this link and customize it to implement your functionality...

[MultiSelect Rows & Cells simultaneously](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q352074.aspx)

check the following thread, which using indicator but you can customize it hiding indicator and setting select option to cellselect etc...
 "[mulitiselect without CTRL key](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q148092.aspx)" on Devexpress..

[search result](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=mutiple%20select%20grid%20rows&p=T4%7CP1%7C56&d=3071) that help you implement that you are looking for...